# Forms not clickable inside div in HTML

Tags: html, css, django

I am writing an app in Django and it works perfectly fine when not including divs but when including divs, I cannot click on any forms or texts after the post request (weirdly, it works fine before the post request).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
<body>
<div style="width:1200px;">
    <div style="width:300px; float:left;">


          {% block content %}

            <form method="post" action="">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
              </table>
              <input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
            </form>

            <li><a href="{% url 'app_name' %}">Some text</a></li>
           {% endblock %}


        </div>

    <div style="width:900px; float:right"; >

            Some text       

        </div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

I am very new to HTML but I read that it is related to CSS somehow but I want to avoid fiddling with that when using Django.

Comment: Ehm, you have a <div> around the <body> there, that can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` tag should go immediately after `<head>`. Close out the `<body>` tag at the end of your code.

Comment: I changed that and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some conventions which need to follow while working in HTML.

1. we write html just like xml (Open tag and closing tag)
2. html tag is the root element of DOM
3. In html, we have two major tags: head and body
4. In head, we normally add dependencies tags required to our web page and meta data of our page and this part this not visible to user in browser's view
5. In body, we write code that we can see in browser
6. divs, spans, input fields, forms and all other tags should be inside the body
7. So according to 1 - 6, you are violating the conventions of html. You need to include your all div tags under body

Comment: Well, it does not help to put the div inside the body tag - it is still unclickable.

Comment: @PeterAlexander Can you post the generated HTML? Maybe we're missing something.